# Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 3209.

Tags: summation, least-common-multiple

Please help me. This problem is part of a captcha program and I cannot bypass it.

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 3209.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I cannot believe that we have captchas like this.  Anyways find multiples of 3, 5 add them up. Subtract multiples of 15

Comment: Take a step back from the problem.  What is the sum of all multiples of $3$ below $3209$?  What is the sum of all multiples of $5$ below $3209$?  Finally, how would you account for the overlap of those numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3209 = 3(1069) + 2 $ So we need to find the sum $S_1 = 3+6+9 + \cdots + 3207$

$3209 = 5(641) + 4$ and the sum $S_2 = 5 + 10 + 15 + \cdots 3205$

$3209 = 15(213) + 14$ and $S_3 = 15 + 30 + 45 + \cdots 3195$

The total sum would be $S = S_1 + S_2 - S_3$.

Since $15, 30, 45, \cdots$ are common with both $S_1 , S_2$ so it count twice hence we should subtract them once. The sum of arithmetic series equal to the sum of the first and the last term multiplied with the half number of the terms

$S_1 = \frac{1069}{2}(3 + 3207)$

Comment: Thank You, may I ask how that would be expressed as a whole number.

Comment: What do you mean by  "whole number "?

Comment: Well, it says the final answer must be a whole number. Does that not sound right?

Comment: It means an integer, i.e., no fractions or decimals and no negative.

Comment: $S$ is a whole number